# Can Computer Vision (Microsoft Azure) be set to only output specific image tags?

Tags: azure, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I'm not really too familiar with the programming/coding aspect of Computer Vision. What I can tell from a functional perspective is that it's analyzing an image, then outputting tags based on what it sees. The issue is that the Plugin I use in Wordpress doesn't filter the response of that image analysis. It basically takes my API Key and then echoes the response it receives from Computer Vision to display all of the image tags.

That being said, I have a fairly straight-forward yes or no question. Can Computer Vision be set up to only output specific image tags if they are present in the image? If so, where can I find information on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm looking at the API reference here: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-2/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499f21b

There does not appear to be any setting allowing one to filter the image tags returned by the service. It also appears that the only format it will return a response in is JSON. So the answer would be no.